# Blender Mouse Over not returning correct HitObject

Tags: python, controller, mouse, sensors, blender

So I have a Python controller which has two sensors hooked up to it, a Mouse Left Button sensor and a Mouse Over sensor, both have TRUE level triggering enabled with a frequency of 0.  The Python controller is linked to a script which is shown below:

```
# Gather information.
scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene();
camera = scene.active_camera;
controller = GameLogic.getCurrentController();

# Change to Earth camera.
clicked = controller.sensors['MouseClick'].positive;
if clicked:
    hitObject = controller.sensors['MouseOver'].hitObject;
    if hitObject is not None:
        print(hitObject.name);
        if(hitObject.name == 'Earth'):
            scene.active_camera = 'Earth Camera';
    else:
        print('Nothing hit!');
```

Basically, it is supposed to check if the mouse's left button was clicked, and if so grab the hitObject of the mouse over sensor and print out the name of it, if the mouse over object is None, it prints out "Nothing hit!".  However, in the game when I click on an object (such as the Earth, which is hard to miss clicking on) all it does is print out, "Nothing hit!".

Is there something wrong with the way I am using the sensors?  Is my Python incorrect here?  Why is `controller.sensors['MouseOver'].hitObject` always of type `None`?

Answer (score 0):

the object, you want to click should not have the Physics Type 'No Collision'. I know that 'Static' works.

Good luck.